# Tensorflow is not importing on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have installed tensorflow on my linux desktop and I have tried importing it in the terminal which worked. But when I tried the same thing on jupyter notebook, I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

To install tensorflow I have followed below steps:

1. `conda create -n tensorflow_env python=3`
2. `source activate tensorflow_env`
3. `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: have you chosen the same kernel from jupyter ?

Comment: Did you open jupyter notebook from within the virtual environment that you ahve installed tensorflow in?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please install your conda environment using the below command in terminal

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name tensorflow_env.
```

After installation,

```
1)reload your jupyter notebook.
2)In jupyter notebook, click on kernel->change kernel->tensorflow_env.
3)open new notebook with kernel "tensorflow_env"
4)Try importing tensorflow.
```